# The capturing group in the regular expression isn't output

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
    $string = 'This is my regular expression';
    $array = array();
    preg_match('/^.*((my)? regular (expression)?)$/i', $string, $array);
    var_dump($array);
?>
```

After execution of this script I have:

```
array (size=4)
    0 => string 'This is my regular expression' (length=29)
    1 => string ' regular expression' (length=19)
    2 => string '' (length=0)
    3 => string 'expression' (length=10)
```

Why it doesn't output capturing group (my)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have a greedy quantifier `.*` before it. You should instead use a non greedy quantifier `.*?`.

Do it as follows instead:

```
<?php
    $string = 'This is my regular expression';
    $array = array();
    preg_match('/^.*?((my)? regular (expression)?)$/i', $string, $array);
    var_dump($array);
?>
```

### DEMO

```
[OUTPUT]

array (size=4)
0 => string 'This is my regular expression' (length=29)
1 => string 'my regular expression' (length=21)
2 => string 'my' (length=2)
3 => string 'expression' (length=10)
```